# Advice on adding index in db2

Tags: database, performance, indexing, database-design, db2

Good day,

In my java web application, I have a table, which having 107 columns, and this table also a parent table, and having many child tables. Currently this table is having more than 10 millions row of records in production.

Since last year, the java web application keep hitting slowness issue. After checking and debugging, we found that the slowness is happen during update or select data from this table.

Every time having this issue, I will take the select query or update query to run a `db2advis` command to check its result, and everytime I am getting result that need >99% improvement to apply the recommended indexes. After add those indexes, will solve the slowness issue.

So until now, there are already 7~8 indexes being apply in this table. Today, I am being reported there is a slowness issue again. After checking, found that its also slowness issue during a select statement from this table and join other table. Same way, I run the `db2advis` command and result also >99% improvement and few recommended indexes.

However, I am starting to question myself, is all these solution is a good solution? If there is another slowness issue in future, should I apply the same solution again?

And everytime I get the result of `db2advis`, it will also have a part of unused existing indexes that list of drop index query, those indexes are the index that I insert previously. I believe this is because of those indexes is not related to current query for `db2advis`? So I can ignore this? Or these existing indexes will affected the performance?

As my understanding, there are disadvantage for index also, specially for insert and update statement.

Additionally, there is a policy for the system owner to keep the data for at least 7 years, thus, the owner is not going to do housekeeping for the database.

Would like to ask for advice, other than add index, and change the query to better query, is there any other way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Typically, indexes serve not a single query, but a workload. The more indexes you have, the slower the insert/update/delete performance. The more indexes you have, the more memory is needed to hold them. Without knowing your schema and your app and seeing numbers, nobody will give a serious advice.

Comment: Check out the concept of hot, warm and cold data for your 7 year policy. Likely that a single won't fix it, but a redesign.

Comment: Every index has a cost. It makes changes in data slower and increases disk usage. As a personal heuristic, I put my limit on 10 indexes. Beyond that point I start to heavily optimize them and I'll combine two or more into a single one, when possible.

Answer (score 3):

This answer contains general advice about levers that may be available to you.

Your situation happens in many companies that are subject to regulatory requirements for multi-year online data retention.

When the physical data model is not designed to exploit range-partitioning for easy roll out of old data (without delete), performance can degrade over time especially when business changes or legal changes impact data distributions.

Your question is not about programming, but instead it is about performance management, and that is a big topic.

Because of that reason, your question may be more suitable for **dba.stackexchange.com**. This stackoverflow website is intended for more specific programming questions.

Always focus on the whole workload, not only a single query. A "good solution" for one query may be bad for another aspect of functionality.
Adding one index can speed up one query but negatively impact other insert/update/delete activities, as you mention.
Companies that have a non-production environment that has the same (or higher) volumes of data with matching distributions can exploit such environments for performance-measurement , especially if they have a realistic test workload-generator and instrumentation for profiling.

Separately, keep in mind the importance of designing the statistics collection properly - sometimes column-group-statistics can have a big impact to help index selection even for existing indexes, other times the use of distribution-statistics can greatly help dynamic SQL, and statistical-views can help with many problems. So before adding new indexes always consider if other kinds of techniques can help especially if the join columns are already indexed correctly, and foreign-key indexes are present , but for some reason the Db2-optimiser is ignoring the indexes.

If the Db2 index lastused column (in `syscat.indexes`) shows that an index is never used or used extremely rarely, then you should investigate why the index was created, and why some queries that might be expected to benefit from that specific index are ignoring the index. Sometimes, it's necessary to reorder the columns in the index to ensure that the highest selectivity columns are at the lowest ordinal position.

There are other levers you can adjust, MQT, MDC, optimisation profiles (hints), registry settings, optimisation-levels, but the start point is a good data model and good measurements.

Comment: Hi @mao , I will post this to dba.stackexchange.com and share you the post. Do u mind I close this post?